# dompdf special characters

Tags: dompdf

I'm having successful html-to-pdf conversions, but not with special characters.

Below is just a special character I'm trying to display, which displays in browsers on my Mac, when I put it simply inside an html document. (but not on my windows box)

```
<?php
require_once("../dompdf_config.inc.php");
$html = '&#8364;';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); $html = iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1250',$html);
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("contract.pdf");
exit(0);
?>
```

I keep getting a "?" (question mark) when the pdf is rendered.
I know there's been lots of issues documented with regards to special characters, but I thought I'd give this a try, with the code I'm actually using.

If DomPdf isn't a recommended html-to-pdf conversion tool, I'll take any other recommendations!

Comment: Is the character you are trying for represented within the font you are using within the PDF?

Comment: I didn't know that was a factor.  How would I find that out?

Answer (score 18):

I have experienced problems with DOMPDF when converting an UTF-8 html page.
I simply solved the problem by adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Between < head > tag.
Maybe it could be an alternative if you set it with your encoding type.

**IMPORTANT NOTE from comments below:** don't use **stream()** and **output()** methods on the same pdf instance. If you do this wont work.

Comment: I lost so much time here, don't use `stream()` and `output()` methods on the same pdf instance. If you do this wont work.

Comment: This symbol "<" is not getting printed in my Dom Pdf Please Help

Comment: @JigneshMistry try using &lt; instead

Comment: Cant add as data saved in database is as follows "Nasal Congestion with obstruction< night. Otherwise improved. Last Med...Kali carb 1M" so after obstruction nothing gets displayed in dompdf

Comment: Replace with "obstruction&lt; night"

Answer (score 10):

after trying all solutions on the net. I could solve without modifying the dompdf. the problem was on the html content. I just had to add the correct and appropriate HTML structure and setting the font of course . Tested on  v0.6.0 and v0.6.1. here I leave the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>your content ćčžšđ...</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

DOMPDF Latin Turkish (Türkçe) char problem, my solution %100 Work.

Server requirenment control:
[image: Server requirenment control]

Char 'dejavu sans mono' (Turkish support) OR:

**Step 1: dompdf_config.inc.php edit to**

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
def("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
```

**Step 2: lib/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php edit to add code:**

```
'futural' => 
  array (
    'normal' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'FUTURAL',
    'bold' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'FUTURAL',
    'italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'FUTURAL',
    'bold_italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'FUTURAL',
  ),
```

**Step 3: doqnload font files to copy lib/fonts folder.**
[Download font files Link](http://www.2shared.com/file/k6hdky_b/fonts.html) http://www.2shared.com/file/k6hdky_b/fonts.html

**Step 4: Your code Edit example:**

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
$html='<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style>
    html{padding:-30px;}
    body { font-family: futural; }
</style>
</head><body>';
$html.='ı İ Ş ş ç Ç ö Ö ü Ü ğ Ğ ÿ þ ð ê ß ã Ù Ñ È »  ¿ İsa Şahintürk';
$html.='</body></html>';
if ( isset( $html ) ) {
    if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
    $html = stripslashes($html);
    $old_limit = ini_set("memory_limit", "16M");
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html,'UTF-8');
    $dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');// or landscape
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("limitless.pdf");
exit(0);
}
```

End Finish PDF > example[image]
http://limitsizbilgi.com/pdf/dompdf-chartest.pdf

Comment: My server was missing the mbstring extension. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 5):

You must use another character set. For example dejavu Sans Mono. Add your code

```
<style>
*{
    font-family:"DeJaVu Sans Mono",monospace;
}
</style>
```

I also mentioned it in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDwupJ-AFPI) video.

Answer (score 4):

Anything prior to 0.6.x has limited support for characters outside iso-8859-1 encoding. The Euro is supported in 0.5.x by using the appropriate Windows ANSI character code (`&#0128;`), but otherwise you have to jump through some PDF encoding hoops.

The 0.6.0 release has better support for "special" characters. The default encoding is based on Windows ANSI (one of the few recognized by the PDF 1.3 spec). You can enable better character support by loading a Unicode-based font and enabling Unicode in dompdf and specifying that encoding in your document.

The following should work in dompdf 0.6.0 or greater:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <p>€</p>
</body>
</html>
```

(or to be lazy just use the euro entity `&euro;` in your test)

There is a document outlining the steps needed to [enable Unicode support in DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo). 
Plus read this answer for an [overview of how to load fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24517882/264628).