# Dompdf on Laravel 5.1 Greek chars

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, dompdf

I am using Laravel 5.1 and I ve installed laravel-dompdf to my project. Unfortunately dompdf is not working for Greek characters. 
I am using a simple view with lite html code and I have added in my header the meta tag charset utf8.
My view is working correctly as html page but when I use pdf stream or download dompdf methods Greeks are like question marks 
Is there any solution?
Thank u

Comment: This may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384517/dompdf-character-encoding-utf-8

Comment: @VinodVT thanks for your comment. My problem is **solved...**