# How to print &ge; sign in a PDF generated with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, encoding

I'm having trouble trying to print a greater-than-or-equal-to sign in a PDF generated with PHP-TCPDF.

I already tried these things, without any success:

```
$pdf = new \TCPDF(/** some options **/, $unicode = true, $encoding = 'UTF-8');
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('times');

$pdf->Cell(100, 5, "test &ge;", 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(100, 5, "test &#x2265;", 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(100, 5, "test &#8805;", 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(100, 5, "test \u2265", 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(100, 5, "test " . json_decode('"\u2265"'), 0, 1);
```

which result in

```
With ->Cell      | With ->WriteHtmlCell
---------------- | --------------------
test &ge;        | test ?
test &#x2265;    | test ?
test &#8805;     | test ?
test ?           | test \u2265
test ?           | test ?
```

Is there a way to print this special char? Using a special font? I searched the web and found that Times supports this sign (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2265/fontsupport.htm)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified that the used font contains the "greather-than-or-equal-to" sign? Maybe it's simply not included. Try using another font.

Comment: Did you try >>>>>>> ?

Comment: Have u tried FPDF? It is much simpler in pdf stuffs!

Comment: I tried with the font Times which is bundled in the library, but that still doesn't work... and I don't know how to dig into this file to search for the char

Comment: this thread might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/28275388/4098311