# Dom-pdf not rendering some characters

Tags: php, pdf-generation, laravel-5.1, dompdf

Im using [vsmoraes/laravel-pdf](https://github.com/vsmoraes/pdf-laravel5) for pdf generation. Its working fine for english characters but when its comes to other languages like `chinese, greek` its showing the `????` as below image

[image]

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384517/dompdf-character-encoding-utf-8) one but went wrong. Anybody had this problem before?

Comment: https://github.com/vsmoraes/pdf-laravel5/issues/14 may this help you

Comment: Also read through the [Dompdf Unicode How-To](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo). Chinese characters require extra work, but you can get Greek by using the bundled DejaVu fonts.