# Turkish characters not showing on dompdf output

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, dompdf, html-to-pdf

I am using 0.7.0 dompdf to generate pdf file from html. I can create pdf file but it doesnt show Turkish Characters. Here are my codes:

PHP code to generate pdf by using dompdf:

```
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    use Dompdf\Options;

    $pdfresult=$gotoclass->generatepdf();

    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');

    require_once '../../include/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('defaultFont', 'Courier');
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

    $dompdf->loadHtml("$pdfresult");

    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

    $dompdf->render();

    $dompdf->stream();

    unset($pdfresult);
    unset($dompdf);
```

if I delete `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');` part from code then it gives following IteratorAggregate error:

> Fatal error: Interface 'IteratorAggregate' not found in
>   /public_html/include/dompdf/src/Frame/FrameTreeList.php
>   on line 14

How can I fix this problem and show Turkish characters in pdf? Appreciate for your helps!

Comment: The FrameTree iterator issue seems to be a separate issue from your character display problems that might need to be addressed by the Dompdf team.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dompdf character encoding UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384517/dompdf-character-encoding-utf-8)

Comment: Possibly related issue: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1355