# Dompdf UT8 with database records with accents

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I have a problem with utf8 with my stored data with dompdf for laravel: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

My column collation is set to

```
utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

In my html file I use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

So when I write in my html file : éééé and I generate the PDF it's file but when I display my stored data the accents are displayed by : ?

[image]

In my config/dompdf.php

I have set :

```
  "DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED" => true,
  "DOMPDF_PDF_BACKEND" => "CPDF",
```

What am I doing wrong? The problem only come from my stored data.. Hope someone could help thanks a lot in advance.

When I display my blade page without dompdf on firefox it's also really strange I get spaces between the accents :

[image]

But with Chrome all is fine ..

[image]

Also when i trie to pass a variable with a accent to my dompdf view the content of the variable is not display when there is an accent

```
$fede = 'fé'; // not display 
$fede = 'fe'; // is displayed as well..
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dompdf character encoding UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384517/dompdf-character-encoding-utf-8)

Comment: Seems like there may be hidden characters after some of the accented characters. Can you please paste some problem text directly? We cannot check the text from an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue before , and i changed many things but i couldn't make it to work , then i switched to **niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf** and it worked like sharm , give it a try and see

Comment: all right man, yes i had the same idea to switch to another one and this one looks good. I will try it and let you know, thanks a lot man

Comment: Still the same with this package ... :( also my css is not read. what is your config ?