# how to display Malayalam character in dompdf pdf in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf to load PDF's in my laravel application. I need to display malayalam letters.

it displays ?????? when I am trying to display

Comment: Please look into this if this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384517/dompdf-character-encoding-utf-8