# how to remove ???? from dompdf generator

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

This is my code how to show Arabic font letters instead of question mark and font to include in pdf.
function

```
pdf_create($html, $filename, $stream=TRUE) 
    {
        require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
        $date=date("m_d_Y");
        $filename = $filename.'_'.$date.'_'.rand();
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');   
        $dompdf->load_html($html);        
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream("$filename".".pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
    }
```

Immediate solution are appreiated.wait for solution from yester

Comment: Check this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136067/dompdf-special-characters

Comment: ok i check. Thank you.

Comment: Will Helvetica font support for Arabic letters 
مساعدة like this or Any special font i have to download.

Comment: Hi font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif; when i use this font i am getting question mark how use this font in my dompdf

Comment: FYI the core fonts only support characters from the Windows ANSI character set. In order to display characters from other encodings you have to use one of the included Deja Vu fonts (e.g. Deja Vu Sans) in dompdf 0.6.0 or greater or [load a custom font](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24517882/264628).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working

In php page put below code in head. 
The issue was in my css font so only i got Arabic letters as ????? in pdf

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8"/>
```

In css

```
th
            {
                font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
                /*font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;*/ This is wrong
                border: solid 1px black;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
```